# Somar + 1 ao número atual (Jquery)

Tags: jquery

Olá!

A seguinte função abaixo, deveria somar + 1, ao `id` atual, porém, não está funcionando, ao contrário de somar, está acrescentando + 1.

Exemplo: Se o ID atual é 1, utilizando a função, o próximo ID (`1 + 1`), deveria ser `2`; entretanto está sendo feito a seguinte forma (`1 + 1 = 11`).

```js
function novo_id(lista) {
    var id = 0;
 //console.log(id);
    if (lista.length > 0) {  
        for (var i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
            if (lista[i].id > id) {
                id = lista[i].id
   }
  }
        id = id + 1;
 }
    return (id == 0 ? 1 : id);
}
```

Comment: experimenta `id = Number(id) + 1;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isso acontece quando misturas String e números com o operador `+` que é de soma mas também de concatenação. O JavaScript usa o operador como "soma" ou como concatenação dependendo do operandos.

```js
function novo_id(lista) {
  var id = 0;
  //console.log(id);
  if (lista.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
      var _id = Number(lista[i].id);
      if (_id > id) id = _id
    }
    id = id + 1;
  }
  return (id == 0 ? 1 : id);
}

console.log(novo_id([{id: '20'}]));
```

Outra maneira de fazer isso ainda mais simples seria assim:

```js
function novo_id(lista) {
  const ids = lista.map(el => Number(el.id));
  return Math.max.apply(Math, ids) + 1;
}

console.log(novo_id([{id: '230'}, {id: '10'}])); // 231
```

Comment: Funciona, mas a outra resposta está mais limpa.
Obrigado pelo retorno.

Comment: @WagnerFilho como achares. A outra resposta está a fazer conversão de tipos aqui `lista[i].id > id`. Ou seja `String > Number`. Eu não gosto disso pois pode dar erros, daí a minha resposta com `Number()` logo no inicio do loop.

Comment: @WagnerFilho juntei mais outra maneira. Mais limpo que isso é difícil :)

Comment: perfeito este segundo.
Obrigado.

Comment: @WagnerFilho se `lista` estiver vazia podes usar `const ids = lista.map(el => Number(el.id)).concat(0);`.

Answer (score 3):

O parâmetro deve estar chegando na `function novo_id(lista)` como *string*. Usa a função [parseInt](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) antes da soma:

```
function novo_id(lista) {
    var id = 0;
    //console.log(id);
    if (lista.length > 0) {     
        for (var i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
            if (lista[i].id > id) {
                id = lista[i].id
            }
        }
        id = parseInt(id) + 1;
    }
    return (id == 0 ? 1 : id);
}
```

Comment: Funcionou (Obrigado)...

Comment: vou marcar, é porque ainda não está permitindo, tenho que aguardar mais um minuto.

Comment: Duas sugestões: `#1` - `lista[i].id > id` está a forçar tipagem. Era melhor converter `lista[i].id` em `Number` antes dessa comparação. `#2` -  Se o `lista[i].id` vier `08` [em browsers antigos isso vai dar outros números](https://stackoverflow.com/q/850341/2256325).

Comment: @Sergio, só um dúvida.
E se não existir um ID, ele terá que partir do 1, como posso fazer isto com o seu método ?